# Package required to install for opening .grb files

Tags: command-line

I don't know which package is required to open .grb files. Please help me.

best.
bsourav69.

Comment: One question on this is enough http://askubuntu.com/questions/655982/package-needed-to-open-grd-files

Comment: The question has changed. ".grb" files are grib files and can be opened by zyGRIB available in software center.